# problem with invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $V$ unitary space.
How to prove that if $T:V\rightarrow V$ and $V\ge U$ is invariant subspace of $T$, then $U^⊥$ is invariant subspace of $T^*$.

I know the meaning of invariant subspace but i can't find the connection between $T^*$ and $U^⊥$,
Can someone help me?

Comment: correct i'll edit

Comment: What is a unitary space?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in U^\perp$ and $y\in U$ then

$$\langle T^* x,y\rangle=\langle  x,\underbrace{Ty}_{\in U}\rangle=0$$
so $T^*x\in U^\perp$ and the result follows.

Comment: now i understand, tnx!

Comment: You're welcome.